# I have a watch app that builds, but won't install on a watch

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, watchos

When I try to build my watch app, I receive an error message of "Failed to install the app on the device."

It used to run previously before I upgraded to Xcode 15. Tried looking at the signing, but couldn't see where the problem is.

Builds works fine on simulator, but only fails when I try to install on an actual watch via phone.

When I click on details

```
Failed to install the app on the device.
Domain: com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError
Code: 3002
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2024-01-04 03:46:12 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDEInstallCoreDeviceWorker;
    NSURL = "file:///xxxxxx";
}
--
Unable to Install “App Name ”
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Please try again later.
Recovery Suggestion: Extensionless WatchKit app com.xxxx.xxxx.watchkitapp has a WatchKit extension.
--
Extensionless WatchKit app com.xxxx.xxxxx.watchkitapp has a WatchKit extension.
Domain: MIInstallerErrorDomain
Code: 143
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "-[MIInstallableBundle _verifyPluginKitPlugins:extensionKitExtensions:inWatchKit2App:checkAppexSignatures:checkFrameworkSignature:error:]";
    LegacyErrorString = WatchKitExtensionlessAppWithWKExtension;
    SourceFileLine = 901;
}
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_isCoreDevice" = 1;
    "device_isWireless" = 1;
    "device_model" = "Watch6,4";
    "device_osBuild" = "10.2 (21S364)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.watchos";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "355.7.6";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.40.14.100.2";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = "arm64_32";
    "operation_duration_ms" = 1689;
    "operation_errorCode" = 143;
    "operation_errorDomain" = "com.apple.dt.CoreDeviceError.3002.IXUserPresentableErrorDomain.1.MIInstallerErrorDomain";
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDEInstallCoreDeviceWorker;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.watchos";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 99;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 2049;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application.watchapp2";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "watchos10.2";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "10.2";
    "sdk_variant" = watchos;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 14.1.2 (Build 23B92)
Xcode 15.1 (22502) (Build 15C65)
Timestamp: 2024-01-03T21:46:12-06:00
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out - needed to disable signing on the pods

Comment: This would be a better answer if you showed how to disable signing on the pods.